# How to sign an ad-hoc iOS build without beta-reports-active entitlement?

Tags: ios, code-signing, ad-hoc-distribution, entitlements

I'm trying do an ad-hoc distribution of an app, I'm building it succesfully but getting the next error when trying to install it though iTunes:

```
MIS: entitlement 'beta-reports-active' has value not permitted by provisioning profile 'name_of_prov_file'
```

The beta-reports-active field is not set in the ad-hoc provisioning file, which is fine, but for some reason this entitlement is being added to the app in the embedded.mobileprovision file within the IPA. I think this is the problem.

I tried specifying a custom entitlements plist with:

```
 <dict>
   <key>application-identifier</key>
   <string>xxxxxxxx</string>
   <key>beta-reports-active</key>
   <false/>
 </dict>
```

This is showing up in the IPA in the archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent file. But the embedded.mobileprovision file still has it set to true.

I'm using these export options:

```
   <key>method</key>
   <string>ad-hoc</string>
   <key>uploadSymbols</key>
   <true/>
   <key>teamID</key>
   <string>xxxxxxxxxxxx</string>
   <key>compileBitcode</key>
   <false/>
```

And these commands:

```
xcodebuild -alltargets -configuration Release clean build archive -archivePath $PWD/build/archive.xcarchive -scheme projectname -sdk iphoneos9.3 "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=${CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY}" "CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS=entitlements.plist"
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $PWD/build/archive.xcarchive -exportPath $PWD/build/ -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist
```

It's a Cordova application so it's not being developed with XCode and this is a Jenkins automated build.

Note: I can successfully do an app-store build for test flight, this is not what this questions is about.